# Replace zeros in a list with last nonzero value

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, pattern-matching

This question is closely related to the problem of zero crossings.

Suppose I have a list l = {-1, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1}

and I want to replace the zeros with the previous nonzero value, like this:

{-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1}

A rather clunky way to do this is with:

```
  f = TimeSeries[l /. 0 -> Missing[], 
MissingDataMethod -> {"Interpolation", InterpolationOrder -> 0}]
```

Then indeed `f[-1 + Range@Length@l]`gives the required result.

However, there must be a more elegant way to achieve same, with patterns.

Can anyone supply a suggestion?

Comment: What should happen when the first element is a zero?

Answer (score 18):

#### [`SequenceReplace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceReplace.html)

```
SequenceReplace[ p:{a_, 0..} :> Sequence @@ (p /. 0 -> a)] @ l
```

> {-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1}

or

```
FixedPoint[SequenceReplace[{a_, 0} :> Sequence[a, a]], l]
```

> {-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1}

#### [`ReplaceRepeated`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceRepeated.html)

An alternative way to use `ReplaceRepeated` with a single replacement rule:

```
l //. {a___, b_, 0, c___} :> {a, b, b, c}
```

> {-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1}

#### [Memoization](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/WriteAFunctionThatRemembersComputedValues.html)

Memoize the last non-zero value (inspired by @WReach's answer):

```
f[x_] := (f[0] = x; x) 
f /@ l
```

> {-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1}

#### [`Split`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Split.html) + [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html)

```
Split[l, #2 == 0 &] /. p : {a_, 0 ..} :> (p /. 0 -> a) // Flatten
```

> {-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1}

#### [`TimeSeries`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeSeries.html) + [`MissingDataMethod`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MissingDataMethod.html)

Using the `"Values"` property with OP's `f`:

```
f["Values"]
```

> {-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1}

Comment: One of the reasons I asked this question even though I had a working (although inelegant) solution was to see all the creative ways in which MMA experts are able to use the Wolfram language to solve a problem.  Outstanding!

Comment: What sort of (Mathematica) black magic is this!? My +1 sir.

Answer (score 17):

Define a simple function, using `FoldList`

```
op = FoldList[If[#2 == 0, #1, #2] &];

l = {-1, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1};

op@l
(* {-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1} *)
```

Comment: This must be the fastest (and simplest) of the lot. The one I knew existed, but never reached.

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps something like this will appeal

```
l //. {{a___, 1, 0, b___} -> {a, 1, 1, b}, {a___, -1, 0, b___} -> {a, -1, -1, b}}
```

Comment: This is the kind of thing I was aiming for, but I couldn't find the right formulation.  I find patterns such a challenge (although I do use them extensively).  Anyway that you for a great solution.

Answer (score 6):

Given:

```
list = {-1, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1}
```

Then:

```
Module[{prev = 0}, Replace[list, {0 :> prev, x_ :> (prev = x)}, {1}]]

(* {-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1} *)
```

The initial value assigned by `prev = 0` is only used for lists that start with a zero -- choose another value if desired.

Answer (score 5):

A few more...

```
l = {-1, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1};

Do[If[l[[i]] == 0, l[[i]] = l[[i - 1]]], {i, 2, Length[l]}]

l
```

> {-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1}

```
fn[l_] := Block[{l1 = l},
  Set[Part[l1, #[[2]]], Part[l1, #[[1]]]] & /@ SequencePosition[l, {_, 0}];
  l1
]

l = {-1, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1};

FixedPoint[fn, l]
```

> {-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1}

```
l = {-1, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1};

Fold[{#1, If[#2 == 0, Last[#1], #2]} &, l[[1 ;; 1]], l[[2 ;; -1]]] //Flatten
```

> {-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1}

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {-1, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1};
```

Using `SequenceSplit` (new in 11.3)

```
Flatten @ SequenceSplit[list, {a_, b : 0 ..} :> {a, Table[a, Length @ {b}]}]
```

{-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1}

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {-1, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1};
```

Using `SplitBy`, `SequenceCases` and a suggestion from Syed:

```
patts = {{0 ..}, {a : Except[0], b : 0 ..} :> Array[a &, Length@{b}]};

sp = SplitBy[#, {0 ..}] &@list;

Catenate[sp /. Rule @@@ Thread[SequenceCases[list, #] & /@ patts]]

(*{-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1}*)
```

Or in a simpler way using `SequenceReplace`, as @Syed suggests:

```
patt = {a : Except[0], b : 0 ..} :> Splice@Array[a &, Length@{b} + 1];

SequenceReplace[list, patt]

(*{-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1}*)
```

Comment: `SequenceReplace[list, {a : Except[0], b : 0 ..} :> 
  Sequence @@ ConstantArray[a, Length@{b} + 1]]`. `ReplacePart` functionality is built into `Sequence*` functions. `Flatten` is not a good idea. Consider replacing the `-1` in the second location with `{a}` and rerun the solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your excellent observation, Syed! I think I'll pay more attention to `SequenceReplace` because I haven't used it much. See the update, please. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Looking for a mostly arithmetic solution, I found a function that replaces only the first zero:

```
f[list_] := list + Prepend[ Rest[1 - Unitize[list]] Most[list], 0]
```

Finding the number of repetitions requires patterns:

```
list = {-1, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1};
numberIterations =  Max[ SequenceCases[list, {p : Repeated[0]} :> Length[{p}]]]
Nest[f, list, numberIterations]
(* {-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1} *)
```

Works, but it didn't correspond to what I was looking for.