# Joining constant arrays determined by a subsequence of contiguous block of ones

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, sequence, integer-sequence

I have the following:

```
data = {15, 25, 35, 45, 55, 65, 75, 85, 95, 105};
selector = {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0};
```

I want to create the following list from `data` using `selector`

```
output = {0, 15, 15, 0, 45, 45, 45, 0, 0, 0};
```

The rule is given a contiguous block of `1`s, `output` is created by selecting the element from `data` in the position before the first `1` and creating a constant array of that element that is the same length as that block of `1`s. Else `output` is zero.
*Note: `selector[[1]]` is always `0`*

My solution is the following, but it is not very "Mathematica".

```
foo[data_, selector_] :=
 Block[
  {
   output = ConstantArray[0, Length[data]]
   },
  Do[
   Which[
    selector[[i]] == 0 && selector[[i + 1]] == 1,
    output[[i + 1]] = data[[i]],
    selector[[i]] == 1 && selector[[i + 1]] == 0,
    output[[i + 1]] = 0,
    1 + 1 == 2,
    output[[i + 1]] = output[[i]]
    ],
   {i, Length[data] - 1}
   ];
  output
  ];
```

```
foo[data, selector] == output
```

> True

**Is there a cleaner / quicker way of solving this?**

Timing

```
SeedRandom[1];
n = 100000;
selectorBig = RandomInteger[1, n];
selectorBig[[1]] = 0;
dataBig = RandomInteger[{15, 105}, n];

outputBig=foo[dataBig, selectorBig]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.137602

---

**EDIT**

Adding in a compiled version for completeness (150x faster)

```
fooC =
 Compile[
  {
   {data, _Integer, 1},
   {selector, _Integer, 1}
   },
  Block[
   {
    output = ConstantArray[0, Length[data]]
    },
   Do[
    Which[
     selector[[i]] == 0 && selector[[i + 1]] == 1,
     output[[i + 1]] = data[[i]],
     selector[[i]] == 1 && selector[[i + 1]] == 0,
     output[[i + 1]] = 0,
     1 + 1 == 2,
     output[[i + 1]] = output[[i]]
     ],
    {i, Length[data] - 1}
    ];
   output
   ],
  CompilationTarget -> "C",
  RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
  ];

fooC[data, selector] == output
fooC[dataBig, selectorBig] === outputBig // RepeatedTiming
```

> True

> {0.000815153, True}

Comment: I guess this one might help as well https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/206927/58868 l = (1 - selector)*data; op =  FoldList[If[#2 == 0, #1, #2] &]; selector*op@l

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this might be cleaner, but less performant:

```
foo[data_, selector_] := 
  Flatten[{0, ConstantArray[data[[#1]], #2 - #1]} & @@@ SequencePosition[selector, {0, 1 ...}]]
```

This is more performant:

```
foo[data_, selector_] :=
  Flatten[
    (#[[1]] - #) & /@
      Split[data*(1 - selector), 0 == #2 &]]
```

**Old**

This was incorrect for certain selectors.

```
foo[data_, selector_] :=
  PadRight[
    Flatten[
      {0, ConstantArray[#[[1]], Length[#] - 1]} & /@ 
      TakeList[data, Length /@ DeleteCases[Split[selector, LessEqual], {0 ..}]]], 
    Length[data]]
```

Comment: I think the second one fails with `data={15, 19, 39, 46, 99, 29, 48, 78, 30, 83}` and `selector={0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1}`

Comment: Okay, you should add that test case to your question. The way it was written, I assumed that strings of more than 1 zero would only happen at the end of the selector.

Comment: yes, given the randomized example you provided, I absolutely should not have made that assumption. It's just always clearer with explicit test cases. I saw a section with "Timing" and didn't really pay attention to it because I was trying to solve the functional problem. I made the assumption. It was a bad assumption. It's also a very predictable/human thing to do. So, it's always good to provide explicit test cases.

Comment: I apologise that it wasn't clear, but I did include a test case of `selectorBig` and `dataBig` in addition to the original example. (reposting comment as I could not edit it)

Comment: agreed that I could have given a more general test case as an example

Comment: Added a similarly performant alternative that is (hopefully) correct.

Comment: +1 Very clean solution

Answer (score 3):

#### 1.

```
f1 = #2 ReplaceAll[{
         x : {_} :> Splice @ x, 
         x : {_Integer, __} :> Splice[Table[First @ x, Length @ x]]}]@
     Split[# (1 - #2), #2 == 0 &] &;


f1[data, selector]
```

> ```
> {0, 15, 15, 0, 45, 45, 45, 0, 0, 0}
> ```

#### 2.

```
f2 = #2 MapApply[Splice[Table[#, Length@{##}]]&]@ Split[# (1 - #2), #2 == 0 &]&;

f2[data, selector]
```

> ```
> {0, 15, 15, 0, 45, 45, 45, 0, 0, 0}
> ```

Comment: (+1) Nice, @kglr! :-)

Comment: (+1) Never seen `Splice` before!

Answer (score 2):

My attempt is as follows:

```
FillWithPreviousValue[list_, selector_] := 
Module[{previousValue = None, resultList = {}}, 
MapThread[(If[#2 == 0, AppendTo[resultList, 0];
previousValue = #1, AppendTo[resultList, previousValue]]) &, {list, selector}];
resultList]
```

Testing the function:

```
data = {15, 25, 35, 45, 55, 65, 75, 85, 95, 105};
selector = {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0};
res = {0, 15, 15, 0, 45, 45, 45, 0, 0, 0};

FillWithPreviousValue[data, selector] === res

(*True*)
```

Your second example:

```
data2 = {15, 19, 39, 46, 99, 29, 48, 78, 30, 83};
selector2 = {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1};
res2 = {0, 15, 0, 39, 0, 0, 0, 48, 0, 30};

FillWithPreviousValue[data2, selector2] === res2

(*True*)
```

Comment: I get some error messages with `data={15, 19, 39, 46, 99, 29, 48, 78, 30, 83}` and `selector={0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1}`

Comment: See the update, please! :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
foo4[data_, selector_] := FoldList[helper,({0}~Join~Most[data])*selector];
```

Where

```
helper[0, y_] := y; (* take the new value *)
helper[x_, y_] := x; (* use the previous value *)
helper[x_, 0] := 0;
helper[0, 0] := 0;
```

**Elaboration:**
I realised that I get close to answer if I offset the data and multiply it with the selector `({0}~Join~Most[data])*selector`

> {0, 15, 25, 0, 45, 55, 65, 0, 0, 0}

I couldn't quite work out how to then make the non-zeroes take their previous values but some inspiration hit with a helper function

```
foo4[data, selector] == output
```

> True

Comment: This is 10x faster than `foo` but 10x  slower than `fooC`